# What is the best data Structure to represent a rubik cube in java

Tags: java

In my problem I don't have to solve a rubik cube.. but I have to find how the front side of rubik cube will look like after making few moves according to Singmaster's notation.
What data structure would be the best for represent rubik cube in this problem..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could store all of the states in a multidimensional array like this:

```
Object[][][] test = new Object[3][3][3];
```

Object should be substituted with a class representing a single value on the cubes side. But be aware that this array would also include a value for invisible parts of the cube (in the 3x3x3 example the block in the middle of the cube).

**Update:**

If you wish to work with classes for that problem the representation logic of the cube becomes rather complex.

```
class Cube {
    private CubeSide bottom = new CubeSide();
    private CubeSide top = new CubeSide();
    private CubeSide left = new CubeSide();
    private CubeSide right = new CubeSide();
    private CubeSide front = new CubeSide();
    private CubeSide back = new CubeSide();
}

class CubeSide {
    private CubePart[][] = new CubePart[3][3];
}

class CubePart {
    private String color = "red";
}
```

Well thats a quick possibility in which you have to implement the logic for the possible moves and you have to rebuild the sides after every move. But I wouldn't remove arrays here entirely because you can use the index to identify the CubeParts in the layer you have to move rather easy.

Comment: thank you very much.i tried that isn't there any better way to do that using object oriented concepts

Comment: that would help..thnx

Comment: This is really old, but it is important to think of a rubiks cube not as a number of faces, but a number of blocks. a block with the colors green,red,blue will always have these colors. So I would not use CubeSides but layers. (bottom layer, middle layer, top layer). But of course you can track all that also with sides, I do not say in any form, that this answer is wrong!

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Cube {
    int[] cube = new int[48]; // could be byte or even half byte depending on 
                              // how efficient you need to be.
}

// While most recommend this layout:
//          00 01 02
//          03    04
//          05 06 07
// 08 09 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
// 20    21 22    23 24    25 26    27
// 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39
//          40 41 42
//          43    44
//          45 46 47

// I've found this to be far superior:
// 00 01 02 08 09 10
// 07    03 15    11
// 06 05 04 14 13 12
//          16 17 18 24 25 26
//          23    19 31    27
//          22 21 20 30 29 28
//                   32 33 34 40 41 42
//                   39    35 47    43
//                   38 37 36 46 45 44
```

Answer (score -1):

A Rubik's cube has 8 corners and 12 edges. The best way to represent its state is not to save the color for each face, but to save the state for each piece.

For each corner, it can be in 8 positions with 3 orientations each, so we can write down a number between 0 to 23 to mark its current state. For each edge, it can be in 12 positions with 2 orientations each, again it is a number between 0 to 23. So in total we need to have 20 numbers, each number need 5 bits. 100 bits is enough to represent a state of Rubik's cube. You can use four 32-bit integer or two 64-bit integer to implement this.